# Light without Lightsource in OpenGL 3.0

Tags: opengl, opengl-3, light

I want to add some light to my *OpenGL scene* - but the tutorials I find all make use of one or more point light sources. This is not what I want to have.

So my question: How can I add some kind of **general** light to my scene?

Comment: You're either looking for a sun light (directional light) or ambient light. Those two terms should get you some results on google.

Comment: Do you mean ambient lighting? This is "general" lighting.

Comment: Yes, directional light is the term I was looking for - thanks! :-)